# Get Url for a WCF rest service

Tags: wcf

Is it possible to find the Url for a service and method?

An example:

```
class MainServiceModel {
   public string detailsUrl;
}

class MainService {
  MainServiceModel get() {
    return new MainServiceModel {
      detailsUrl = new Uri("how do I get DetailsService.ShowDetails url?");
    }
  }
}

class DetailService {
   string ShowDetails(string id);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try checking out the `OperationContext`:

```
OperationContext oc = OperationContext.Current;
string wasCalledOn = oc.EndpointDispatcher.EndpointAddress.Uri.ToString();
```

The operation context also contains a wealth of other information about the current operation and parameters for it.

<strike>**Update:** if you want to call Service B from your method in Service A, you should create a client-side proxy in Service A. By doing so, you will get some configuration entries, and then you should be able to easily call a method on Service B from your Service A method.</strike>

*ok, so that's not it....*

Comment: Nice, but how can I get the Uri of another service, not the current one? I see the OperationContext has a constructor taking a channel, but I'm not sure how to get the "Channel" for given service

Comment: @simendsjo: you would have to put that into some kind of a config or something and load it from there...

Comment: Then this design is very bad.. What other options are there for linking services together to allow context dependent browsing between them?

Comment: Thanks for the help so far, but I don't think we're on the same page. I don't want to call some other service, I wish to add url's the user can follow. It's a helper for the clients to avoid knowing the entire API and quickly be able to drill down through the various services.

Comment: @simendsjo: ok, so you want to sort of "report back" other URL's for the user to call? Well, again: are those defined in the standard WCF configuration?? (as they should, IMHO) - then just read that config file and report back those URL's needed.... how else do you typically know about a service?? It should be configured in a config file, IMHO

Answer (score 0):

My very high level idea is create custom ServicHost (and ServiceHostFactory if using IIS). When ServiceHost is instantiated you have access to [service description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicedescription.aspx) and endpoints. You can grab information you need and store them somewhere for later reuse. You will have to use reflection on ServiceType to get operations relative URLs.

Btw. in WCF4 each service already shows this if you enable [help page](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/1487/).